What should be done about "push moderation"?
A loaded question or "push question" is a question designed to advance a certain position, such as "Why is C++ better than Rust?" Although this may be a good question with good answers, it presents a one-sided view. It would be better to ask "Is C++ or Rust better, and why?" (on a site that allows subjective questions)
Even if the question was two-sided, the answers could still be curated in a way to bring the C++-better answers to the top (e.g. by using sockpuppet voting).
Some sites in the network disallow push questions.
Some sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated in a similar way with a hidden bias, by removing questions or answers or banning users who oppose the bias. I call them "push sites". For (silly hypothetical) example, talking about Karl Marx's ideas on economics is liable to get you banned, even if you cite him for something he was actually right about. Writing an answer in C++ on SO is liable to get you banned regardless if it's the best solution to the problem. Those two are just hypothetical, but the problem does occur on some sites. I don't want to name actual names here.
What should be done about this type of moderation? Is it permitted?

This seems like the policy for moderation of such questions needs to be established on a per-site basis, rather than be imposed from here on MSE.

If you have a legitimate concern about moderation, make a complaint to the Community Management team. Vague assertions and leading questions on Meta SE achieve nothing.

@Makyen what is the SE policy on per-site moderation policy?

Push questions are usually produced to stimulate debate and hardly ever reach a conclusion. Push questions sometimes start from false or biased premises which can cause polemics. Whether or not this type of question is accepted must be consulted individually on the local platform META site where there is posting interest.

Both of those question are opinion based and should be closed anyway. Any "which is better" type question is opinion based.

@Greenonline those are allowed on some sites

@Nij the question is if a site is allowed to push

Ah ok, I wasn't aware that they existed...  apart from Hardware Recommendations and Software Recommendations (I guess). Which site(s) are you referring to in your question then? It might have been a good idea to have mentioned or linked them in your question.

Inadequate definitions and ambiguous examples are unhelpful. Clarify what you actually mean, because right now the post just seems to be a vague passive-aggressive complaint that moderation isn't doing exactly what you think it should.

@Nij The question is whether a site is allowed to operate as a push site and if not, what the mechanism for correction is. Was this not clear?


e.g. by using sockpuppet voting

That is already against the rules, 'push moderation' or not.

Writing an answer in C++ on SO is liable to get you banned regardless if it's the best solution to the problem.

Well, no. You will not get banned for a single answer unless the answer is blatant abuse. Anyone who votes to delete a solution to a problem, let alone the 'best' solution, would be in violation of the guidelines for deleting an answer.

but the problem does occur on some sites

You have not provided concrete examples but either there was real abuse of power here, or the answer had other issues in the above answer deletion guidelines and was deleted independently. I find the latter much more likely in practice.

Is it permitted?

No! There should not really be any room for bias in the first place, nor have I seen any in practice. Either an answer is objectively an answer and follows the rules or not, in the former case moderation actions taken against the answer would be unwarranted, no matter how much moderators or curators disagree with the content.
As for just the answers being downvoted, maybe people find them not useful. People are generally allowed to vote as they see fit so long as they do not target specific users or commit vote fraud.

What should be done [...]?

Accounts that engage in sockpuppet voting are typically warned or suspended.
Unwarranted moderation actions should be appealed either by raising an 'In need of moderator intervention' flag or by contacting staff directly if the moderators themselves abuse their power. But again that is extremely rare and I have never seen that happen.
